# Put input before label

Tags: html, css

I have a big problem.
My task is to design a custom form on a custom page in a CMS (JTL). I am using a [plugin](http://kreativkonzentrat.de/store/Contact-Forms) to create this form. The problem is that the labels are in front of the checkboxes. This results in a very bad layout. I cannot change the position of the label in the HTML code and therefore have to use CSS since I am not allowed to use JS.

This is basically the HTML:

```
<li>Question<br/>
<label for="option1">Option 1</label><input id="option1" type="checkbox" /><br/>
<label for="option2">Option 2</label><input id="option2" type="checkbox" /><br/>
<label for="option3">Option 3</label><input id="option3" type="checkbox" /></li>
```

It doesn't really matter if the CSS gets huge since my task is to make it look good at any cost (just no rearranging HTML and not using JS).

Comment: how about using some marins? Could we possibly see some of the css?

Comment: Isn't that just a case of turning the `label` and `input` tags around?

Comment: @Azrael, the OP stated: *I cannot change the position of the label in the HTML code*

Comment: @Azrael - he says he can't alter the HTML. I can't see why the labels would be after the inputs from the HTML posted; they should be first. Must be some CSS we're not seeing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the `float` property on the input.

**Since the checkbox is coming after the label, the float will affect the next element, so don't forget to clear the floating using `clear`, otherwise it will messup your visual!**

```css
input[type="checkbox"] {
  float: left;
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<label for="option1">Option 1</label><input id="option1" type="checkbox" /><br/>
<label for="option2">Option 2</label><input id="option2" type="checkbox" /><br/>
<label for="option3">Option 3</label><input id="option3" type="checkbox" />
```

Comment: nvm im getting confused here

Answer (score 1):

You can float the `<label>`s right and then add a fixed width to each `<li>`

http://jsfiddle.net/ctkhyoy7/

Comment: Sorry! my bad! Didn't read the <li> in OP's snippet (thought that had been added, sorry). +1

Answer (score 0):

You can add a float: left property to the checkboxes.

CSS:

```
input {
    float: left;
}
```

Jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/yzeLpgj0/

Answer (score 0):

You can change it like this in your css http://jsfiddle.net/2ynyb4aL/

```
label{
position:absolute;
margin-left:20px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This should help you alot : http://www.webcredible.com/blog-reports/css/css-forms.shtml?

OR try use :

```
<style type="text/css">
label {
    display: block;
    padding-left: 15px;
    text-indent: -15px;
}
input {
    width: 13px;
    height: 13px;
    padding: 0;
    margin:0;
    vertical-align: bottom;
    position: relative;
    top: -1px;
    *overflow: hidden;
}
</style>
```

Comment: Please do not post code only answers, as over time the links may break and hence the answer become useless for future reference.